# ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
Id                     Field             Data
--------------------------------------------------
1                      A                   Data1
2                      B                   Data2
2                      C                   Data3
3                      C                   Data4
4                      G                   Data5
5                      F                   Data6
5                      B                   Data7
```

I want with a single query (for pagination) to fetch all fields "Data" with an Id containing at least one Field with a value of A, B, C. In the previous example I should retrieve all except "Data5" because Id 4 is the only one that does not contain A, B or C . Expected result: Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data6, Data7.

Thanks, I am newbie with ES and I made a mess with must, should, filters, ....

Answer (score 0):

The following might be helpful to you.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "Field": ["G"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Thanks, but "at least one Field with a value of A, B, C". The table data is a sample. Suppose that Id 4 has an F ....